# A click outside of border-radius behaves differently in Chrome than it does in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, mouseclick-event

Say we have a div.child circle inside a div.parent:

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target); 
});
```

```css
div.child:hover {
      border: 1px solid red !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='parent'>
<div class="child" style="height: 10vw; width: 10vw; padding: 1%; text-center; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 50%;">
Lots of content! Until it overflows! Lots of content! Until it overflows!
</div>
</div>
```

In firefox, if you click anywhere just outside the circle, your click will target the parent.

However, in chrome, if you click within a corner of the bounding box but outside the circle, you will still target the child.

**My question is:
In chrome, is there a simple way to detect that the cursor is outside the circle?  CSS?  JS?**

Preferably, the answer would be something simple that could easily be applied to all rounded-boxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue here. You can add border to the div, use chrome/Firefox toolbars to identify what happens on focus, hover etc. Attaching a screenshot 
[image: Shows on click of :hov element on chrome devtoolbar]

Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

For something like this I would recommend using Konva.js.

And here is the link to the code of a project I did using Konva.js which is able to detect where its clicking (In this case on the nail of a 2d picture frame on a wall to output measurements) and output results regardless of whether using chrome, firefox, etc. The same functionality can be achieved easily for on hover.

Code: https://github.com/JsonTyler/framed/blob/master/assets/js/script.js (starting on line 313 and looking at the tooltip positioning logic)

Live Demo: https://framed.jsonbytes.com/

Explanation of live demo: Basically once you get to the page adjust the scrollers to some height and width. Then push "create". Then choose a background. Lastly choose a frame size to see it appear on the canvas. Hover over the frame to see the frame size. And click on the nail after dragging it to where you want it on the canvas to get realistic measurements of how far it is from the left, right, bottom and top of the canvas.

Konvas.js Documentation: https://konvajs.org/docs/index.html